# How do I make exe file with torch module by using pyinstaller?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyinstaller, exe, torch

[Environment]

- vscode
- Anaconda
- Window

I successfully ran main_for_exe.py in vscode.

When I make exe file using pyinstaller and then ran exe file, however, I have the below error message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAlfg.png)

There were some solutions: "add module to hiddenimports"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wESR.png)

but, it does not work.

Basic modules of python such as "os" and "sys" are successfully loaded, but "No module named numpy" error message appeared. So, I think that modules installed by 'pip' and 'conda' aren't loaded.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem!

I just upgraded the pyinstaller package.

It seems that the pyinstaller package, before upgrade, cannot find the site-package path where the modules installed by anaconda are located.
(Generally site-packe path: "~/anaconda3/lib/site-packages")

In this case, there are two solutions.

1. First, you just upgrade pyinstaller.
2. Second, you add site-package path to hookspath and then run "pyinstaller main.spec".

Comment: You may accept this answer as solution for more people with similar issues to reach it.

Comment: I accepted this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No matter `base` or other virtual conda environments, we need to first activate it then with the command `pip install` executed in integrated Terminal, the module can get its right location, or it will throw No module error.
[image]

Now open your project in VS Code, after activating anaconda environment, run `pip show numpy` to check if its location is `anaconda\lib\site-packages`. If not, please reinstall it, then regenerate .exe, the error should go away.

Reference: [Select and activate Environment](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment).

Comment: Thanks, but I solved this problem by just upgrading pyinstaller.